# Connection error when invoking a transaction on the peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to execute a chaincode I have written with couchdb and java. I use the first-network example for creating the network and instantiate the code. The network is created and the chaincode got installed without any problem. Then I enter the container and execute the transactions. At first it worked fine but suddenly it started giving me this error and now I can’t find a solution. I don't know if it is related with couchdb connection or not.

```
Error: error getting endorser client for invoke: endorser client failed to
connect to peer0.org2.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection:
connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp
172.24.0.9:7051: connect: connection refused"
```

The comand i use to invocke the chaincode is the next one.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"Args":["createCustomer","c1","tom"]}'
```

UPDATE:

Many have asked if the chaincode was installed on peers, I can confirm it is.

Comment: Did you install that chaincode on peer0.org2.example.com?

Comment: Try to: telnet peer0.org2.example.com 7051 if cant reach that peer port, that is something in your network or node that you need to handle.

Comment: This may cause by following error - 1) Either chaincode is not installed on both peers or 2) Your peers are not accessible. To check the peer if it is accessible or not , simply try to access ip_addr:port of peer on firefox, if you get response means peer is accessible, other thing you could check if chaincode is installed on that peer or not ?

Comment: @BrajeshKumar I have try to access like you said to the peer throught firefox but it doenst seem to work, so as you said looks like peers are not accessible. Do you know what could be the problem or solution here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Egoes , it means your port is not open for the peers, check the snippet **ports section**, your peer docker file should look like this.

```
peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me solve ir, I had an error with the ports.